# Quartz.net - How can I run a job every year with a reminder 30 days before?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've decided to give Quartz.net a go. 
Now I am trying to figure out what is the best way to implement its triggers.
What should I do if I want to schedule a job with a certain interval, let's say every X weeks, months or years and I want to setup a trigger which executes a certain amount of time before ... like a reminder?

UPDATE:

I've changed the title and try to update my question. I thought it was a easy one but apparently not.
I've already put together an app which is capable to put together a job and and a schedule (trigger). I was hoping some one could help me to understand if it's better a cron trigger or if there are alternatives ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer my own question after a few weeks spent - randomly - doing some experiments.
I've tried **Quartz.net 2.0** cause the API seemed simpler and I could have taken advantage of some new features like **ICalendarIntervalTrigger**.
Unfortunately this version has quite a few bugs in the **AdoJobStore** module and my triggers wouldn't fire at all (working with **RAMJobStore** was alright but I needed to save my jobs on the DB).
I ended up using **CronTriggers** which are the only ones, apparently, suitable for my recurring events each x weeks, months or years. 
I've found this [site](http://www.cronmaker.com/) which will help me to build my cron expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to schedule your reminder as well.  In other words, create your real job and schedule it at the real time.  Also create a reminder job, and schedule it however far ahead of time as you want.

Comment: If you're looking for execution every X number of weeks, months or years, then DateIntervalTrigger (in Quartz 1.x) or CalendarIntervalTrigger (in Quartz 2.x) is the best match.

Comment: DateIntervalTrigger doesn't seem to be part of Quartz.net 1.0.3 and I've tried Quartz.net 2.x but it's really buggy, especially for the AdoJobStore bits, which I am trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

If your job/task is publicly accessible, I'd first try something like scheduler.codeeffects.com, wsscheduler.com or setcronjob.com instead of coding and maintaining the complex logic myself.